# Differences between CHMOD 755 vs 750 permissions set

Tags: xml, linux, jar, permissions, chmod

I have some files with 755 and I need to change them to 750, but I am not sure if this can affect some process.

I am changing JARs, XMLs, LOGs, and properties files.

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two permission sets?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a handy website to visualize and get the octal for what permission you want https://chmod-calculator.com/

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449179/2641825) to a similar question shares  a very nice illustration with circles.

Comment: [chmod calculator](https://wtools.io/chmod-calculator) allows you to quickly create Linux permissions and understand the differences

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`0755` = User:`rwx` Group:`r-x` World:`r-x`

`0750` = User:`rwx` Group:`r-x` World:`---` (i.e. World: no access)

```
r = read
w = write
x = execute (traverse for directories)
```

Comment: User - means the account user (admin or other added user) in the machine - what's the difference between `Group` and `World`?

Comment: "user" means the account user. Group would mean other people in a defined "group" of users (like members of a group, "lab256" say, would be able to have `r-w` access. World would mean anyone else that can log in to that particular machine.